# on Click with button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is being called when a particular element is clicked

```
$(".clickThis").click(function() {

}
```

I would like to add an HTML button and when it is clicked also call this function

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel">
```

Do I need to add a class name to it or is there a way to target it but element?

Can I add second trigger to call my function like this:

```
$(".clickThis, button").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an ID would be better and fastest. Something like:

```
<input id="cancelButton" type="button" value="Cancel">
```

and then

```
$(".clickThis, #cancelButton").click(function(){ 
  //Your Code here..
});
```

If you want to call it with out changing the HTML, try this:

```
$(".clickThis, :button[value='Cancel']").click(function(){ 
  //Your Code here..
});
```

Comment: Certainly the best practice and the way to avoid problems when buttons are added to the page, yes.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that :-)

[look here for info abt jQuery mult selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

so you can do:

```
$(".clickThis, input:button").click(function() {
```

Comment: That will apply to **all** buttons in the page.

Comment: @justkt. yes it would add to all `input:button` elements on the page. but that is what will happen unless u assign a class or an id to that button

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".clickThis, input[type='button']")
```

The way you have it now it will match the `<button>`-element, not a input with type "button"

Comment: As shown the selector, which works, will apply to **any and all** buttons on the page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the selector "button" will not match input-elements with type "button". If your comment is related to the answer of Neal, your right, but Neal's answer has been edited and didn't contain the example-code with "input:button" before my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a union of jquery selectors using "," as you've shown.

However, as pointed out in comments (and other answers), `button` itself is not a selector.

For maintainability of code it might be better to give your button an id and to use that - or to assign the `clickThis` class to the button.

Answer (score 1):

you can also make a button element, give it a class like:

```
<button class="clicksy">Click Me!</button>
```

and then write a function to grab clicks and do stuff like:

```
$("button.clicksy").click(function(){
      /* do stuff */
});
```