# Calling a jquery query on clicking a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I am trying to call a jquery function on clicking a button in the form and here is the code I am using

Button code :

```
  <input type="submit"  src="images/submitbutton.png" alt="Submit button" name="submit_button" class="submit_button" id="submit_button">
```

Form starting code

```
 <form method="post" action="" id="contactForm">
```

The jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('input[name=submit_button]').submit(function () {     


alert("testing")

.....
```

I tried everything to get the submit button to call the jquery function but to no avail ( I tried using submit() or click() ).

What might I be doing wrong ( This form is located on a html page)

Edit : Just inserted the code of the Jquery function I am trying to run ,I am actually trying to call a php script using ajax and then hide the form and provide a success message if the form is submitted successfully

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit_button').submit(function () {        

            alert("testing")    /*get the email value*/

var name = $('input[name=name]');
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var subject= $('input[name=subject]');
        var message = $('textarea[name=message]');


 data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&subject=' + 
        subject.val() + '&message='  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());


        //disabled all the text fields
        $('.text').attr('disabled','true');



        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "mai.php", 

            //GET method is used
            type: "POST",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     



            //success
            success: function () {              

                    $('.contact_form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                    //show the success message
                    $('.simple-sucess').fadeIn('slow');

                //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                } 



        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411198/on-click-with-button-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the name should be in quotes:

```
$('input[name="submit_button"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

> value [..] An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.

You should probably be using an ID anyway, though.

Also, I don't think you're meant to be using `.submit` on the button. Try using `.click` instead, or `.submit` on the form.

Comment: also, you may need to return true/false depending on how you intend to handle the default behavior of the onsubmit handler

Comment: I tried using that but no avail  ,the code was $(#submit_button).submit(function ()

Comment: You mean `$('#submit_button')`?

Comment: @thescientist,can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Oh, wait, you're using `.submit`. You should either apply that to the form (not the button) or use `.click` instead.

Comment: the natural behavior of the submit event is to submit a form to an "action."  Depending on what the intent of this function is, say validation, you will need to return true or false depending on if validation passed, because if it didn't pass, you would want the form submitting, right?

Comment: and yes, James is right you use the ID of the form, not the button for this, and in the context of my discussion about return

Comment: Thanks everyone ,my issue was I was not pulling in the jquery.latest file and hence it was not working,I was under the impression since I had included a minified version of jquery it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //if submit button is clicked
        $('#submit_button').submit(function () {     
         alert("testing");
        });
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Is your goal is to submit the form by this input button?

Comment: I just updated the question to show what I am actually trying to do,I am trying to call a ajax function within the jquery which will submit the form data to a php mailing form.The mailing form works well..its just this function which is driving me nuts

Comment: try to use an input type button instead of submit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use a type button instead of submit? You can add a return true in the end of your script if you want to refresh the page after clicking the button. =)